# Movie with pregnancy permission, unclothed FTL jumps

Tags: story-identification, movie

I would have watched this movie sometime between 1995-2005. It was almost certainly a North American VHS rental (English).

The movie was set in the future on board a space ship. I only remember two scenes from the movie:

1. At the beginning of the movie, a male and female couple are excited at having been granted permission to conceive a child. Evidently reproduction is restricted in some way in the future.
2. Later, as the small crew (maybe 10 people) are preparing for some sort of FTL jump, they have to strip down naked (for what I'm sure are *entirely plot related reasons*) and get in these pod things to jump safely. There some brief nudity in this scene that was obvious burned into my adolescent mind.

That's pretty much it. I don't think there were any overly famous actors in it and may have been somewhat of a "B-movie".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sounds like the 2000 movie *[Supernova](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0134983/?ref_=tt_mv_close)*.

The crew of *Nightingale 229* receive an distress signal coming from a remote base and d-jumps ("dimension jump") to perform a rescue.  In order to safely d-jump, the crew have to enter individual pods, naked, in order to protect themselves from higher-dimensional space.

Two of the crew, Nick and Kaela want to have a child, but need permission in order to do so.

There is a more complete plot synopsis (though it doesn't dwell on the nudity and sex) at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova_(2000_film)#Plot).

Comment: That definitely fits the bill, although none of the scenes from the trailer itself look familiar. But if those scenes are it, I'd say it's very likely. Looks like there were a few decent actors in it after all (James Spader, Lou Diamond Phillips).